# Ubuntu 18.10 Google online account timeout

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 18.10, google, calendar

so I recently installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my Surface Pro 3. I added my Google account with gnome online accounts and logged in successfully even with 2FA enabled.

However, I noticed that nothing is being synced from my account e.g. Calendar doesn't show any events.

When I try and access gdrive via Files/nautilus it eventually pops up with:

[Nautilus gdrive timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2tXu.png)

Anyone know what I can do to solve this? I have tried deleting and re-adding the account. In the past (previous machines, VM etc.) I have been able to sync just fine.

Comment: what is google ?

Answer (score 0):

you may need an App Specific Password from your google acct